# Calibration and rectification of a stereo Camera with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I want to calibrate and rectify a stereo Camera with OpenCV and Python. The code works, but the rectify camera videos are zoomed in. Where could be the problem? And how can I best test if the calibration and the stereo calibration was successful?

Comment: Add code sample, add images. We can't help with what we can't see.

Answer (score 4):

In the process of undistorting, the image will be warped, cropped and resized. This might have given a sense of zooming in.

[image: Process of Stereo Rectification]

To check whether the stereo calibration is correct, find some key points in the left image and draw the corresponding epipolar lines in the other image, and check whether the epipolar line passes through the corresponding point in the right image.

take a look at this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html)

[image: Left Image with some keypoints]

[image: Right image with corresponding epipolar lines]

Comment: the object points for the calibratecamera function must be in a specific order ? And the return value retL have to be between 0 and 1 ? Because at my calibration it is about 15 ?

Comment: it seems that only a few pixels are visible in the rectified image

Comment: The return value will be the RMS error. For a good calibration, it should be within 0 to 1. If it is not, then the undistortion won't be proper. First calibrate your left and right camera individually, then use the results in stereo calibration

Comment: The object points in calibrate Camera Must be in a specific order? Or what can be wrong if I do not get a good RMS error?

Comment: There can be several reasons. One such reason might be, your image points might not be exactly on the corners. If this is the case, then you try to get exact corners (using cornerSubPix, or preprocessing the image). Your RMS error should be small. OpenCV handles the ordering in case of single camera calibration. In the case of stereo calibration, the left, and right image points should have the same order, if it is Top Left to Bottom right on the left image, the detected points should be of the same order in the right image

Comment: What is a possible set for the object point coordinates in a assymetric grid? columns 11 and rows 4